# What does this stack trace from python requests indicate?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to make a requests call to elasticsearch, I can make this exact same call from a plain script, but if I set a list as a string and pass to the payload, I am getting this stack trace:

I am trying to pass a list as a string to a curl post and python seems to be breaking. Please help.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "moodgb.py", line 79, in <module>
    print(response.text)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 760, in text
    if not self.content:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 733, in content
    self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or bytes()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 656, in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 273, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 186, in read
    self._decoder = _get_decoder(content_encoding)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 57, in _get_decoder
    return GzipDecoder()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 44, in __init__
    self._obj = zlib.decompressobj(16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)
ValueError: Invalid initialization option

Here is the code:
#########
c=str(sorted(set(mysql_alertids)))
#test = str(mysql_alertids)

url = "http://elastic:9900/index%2A/_search"

payload = "{\"size\":10000,\r\n\t\"query\": \r\n\t{\r\n\t\t\"terms\" :\r\n\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\"alert_id\" : "+c+" \r\n\t\t}\r\n\t}\r\n}"
print(payload)
headers = {
    'content-type': "application/json",
    'authorization': "val",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "token"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
#########
```

I should be getting back a list of jsons (Dictionaries)

Comment: have you tried using the `requests.post()` method? The [`docs`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) state the syntax to make an HTTP POST request is `response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting.. adding import zlib solved the issue!

Comment: It does look like bad interplay between `requests, urllib3, zlib` ; Based on line numbers in the traceback, this is **not the latest** urllib3. Please check newer version or changelog in case this was already fixed.