# Python3 ValueError: Invalid initialization option when using requests package

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-requests

I have stumbled upon an error which I could not resolve. When I ran my python code, this error occurs and it only happens when I am making an API call using the **requests** package.

Code calling the API:

```
def getAccs(id):

    accountid = ''
    url = "{}/{}".format(acc_api, id)

    req = requests.get(url, headers=head)
    result = json.loads(req.text)

    if result['id'] is None:
        # Fetches accountid from another api call after updating
        accountid = updateCorp(result['name'], id)
    else:
        accountid = result['id']

    return accountid

if __name__ == "__main__":

    ### Get data from appSettings.json
    with open('appSettingsStg.json') as app:
        data = json.load(app)
    
        acc_api = data['Urls']['Accounts']
    
    # Header
    head = {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "insert.py", line 313, in <module>
    acc.append(res)
  File "insert.py", line 102, in getAccs
    req = requests.get(url, headers=head)
  File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 685, in send
    r.content
  File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 829, in content
    self._content = b''.join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or b''
  File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 751, in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
  File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 571, in stream
    for line in self.read_chunked(amt, decode_content=decode_content):
  File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 738, in read_chunked
    self._init_decoder()
  File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 376, in _init_decoder
    self._decoder = _get_decoder(content_encoding)
  File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 147, in _get_decoder
    return GzipDecoder()
  File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 74, in __init__
    self._obj = zlib.decompressobj(16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)
ValueError: Invalid initialization option
```

Some things I have tried

- Importing zlib and urllib3 (As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54318661/what-does-this-stack-trace-from-python-requests-indicate) post)
- Upgrading requests package (v2.24.0 as of 25/08/2020)
- Reinstalling requests and urllib3 (Didnt work but I thought it was at least worth a try)

Any advice is much appreciated !

Comment: I guess it'd help to see your code as well

Comment: Already added part of the code that crashes when making API call

Comment: what's in `head` ?

Comment: The head (header) has already been declared in if __name__ == "__main__" section